# I'm using hibernate text based search and indexing. I want to search common rows between indexed tables using Lucene query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, text-based

I have 2 tables which are already indexed by hibernate. Now what I am doing is getting all the rows from one table and search in the another table using lucene query iteratively.

As the table size is increasing i am facing the issues with time delays. I hope there must be the way by which we can search among the indexed table without using the iterative approach.